# NoMethodError (undefined method `scoped' for Class:Module):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a has_many and has_many :through relationship that looks like this...

```
class Guestlist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :venues

    has_many :patrons
    has_many :users, :through => :patrons

    attr_accessible :capacity, :end_time, :name, :start_time, :venue_id
end

class Patron < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :guestlists
    belongs_to :users
    attr_accessible :guestlist_id, :user_id, :checked_in
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :patrons
  has_many :guestlists, :through => :patrons
end
```

I am trying to access the users "through" guestlist object...

```
@guestlist = Guestlist.find(params[:id])
@guests = @guestlist.users.order('name ASC')
```

and the following error is thrown...

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `scoped' for Users:Module)
```

I've been searching all over for a solution but nothing works. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks something wrong with your associations in  Model `Patron`.  Singularize `users` and `guestlists`. Refer more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)

```
class Patron < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :guestlist 
    belongs_to :user
    attr_accessible :guestlist_id, :user_id, :checked_in
end
```

Comment: thanks! Still learning rails. has_many relationships should not be singular right?

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know where I can look into how to update the Patrons table which doesn't have any primary keys?

Comment: @Adgezaza.. every association in rails has a singular or plural form associated with it. which just indicates whether the association are one-to-one, one-to-many and so on.  Reading through associations will provide you a good understanding on what basic associations are.  The Patron table aka Join table will be updated on itself when you will insert data into Users or Guestlists.

Comment: The patron table as a field "checked_in" that I want to update though. If I try to do an update on the patron record I get the following error... "Unknown column 'patrons.' in 'where clause': UPDATE `patrons` SET `checked_in` = 1 WHERE `patrons`.`` IS NULL"